# Effect of an added constraint to an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming

If you have a constrained maximization problem, and you add an additional constraint, my intuition says that since the new solution space is a subset of the original solution space, the new max objective value is upper bounded by the old max objective value. Is there a theorem that shows this?

Comment: You are right and your argument is essentially the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A \subset B$, then $\sup_{x \in A} f(x) \le \sup_{x \in B} f(x)$.

If $B$ is the original feasible set, and you add a constraint, then you obtain
a new feasible set $A \subset B$, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Is there a name for this? Or is it just commonly accepted?

Comment: I think it is commonly known.